# How to redirect a page without the page extension

Tags: .htaccess

I am currently working on a signup page and I was wondering if I could modify the URL without the `.php` extension.

For example, it is now

```
www.xyz.com/signup.php
```

And what I would like achieve is

```
www.xyz.com/signup
```

Now I am assuming that I might have to use the htaccess file, but I am not sure about it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove .php extension with .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First rule will redirect from `signup.php` to `domain.com/signup/`.

Second rule will redirect internally so the URL will remain `domain.com/signup/` while displaying the content of `domain.com/signup.php`.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect /signup.php to /signup/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+signup\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /signup/? [R=302,L]

# Internally forward /signup/ to /signup.php
RewriteRule ^signup/?$ /signup.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called `URL rewrite`. Take a look at this tutorial for beginners: http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/.

Comment: I guess thats what I have been looking for.. Thanks Luka, that was quick and perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can duplicate with .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule singup$ singup.php [NC,L]
```